# ロードバランサー直下のサーバのSSL化(Let's encrypt)の方法は以下であってますでしょうか？

Tags: apache, ssl, letsencrypt

ロードバランサー直下に設置したサーバは、以下の様にサブドメインを紐づけてSSL化すればいいのでしょうか?
また、SSL化が終わったロードバランサー直下のサーバはロードバランサー以外からの接続をNGにすれば宜しいのでしょうか?

ロードバランサーのドメイン: srv.example.jp

ロードバランサー直下のサーバのドメイン
srv1.example.jp
srv2.example.jp
srv3.example.jp

```
certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path  /var/www/html -d srv1.example.jp 
certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path  /var/www/html -d srv2.example.jp 
certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path  /var/www/html -d srv3.example.jp
```

以上、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

各サーバーで取得するSSL証明書には、自ホストのドメイン名に加えて、LBのドメイン名が記載されるようにするのが良いと思います。 `-d` オプションを追加すれば 良いみたいなので試してみてください。

certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/html -d srv1.example.jp -d srv.example.jp
certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/html -d srv2.example.jp -d srv.example.jp
certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/html -d srv3.example.jp -d srv.example.jp

Comment: 有難うございます。大変参考になりました。

Answer (score 1):

ロードバランサを用いる場合、SSL(TLS)の構成には2通りあります

### SSL(TLS)の終端をロードバランサが行う

この場合、証明書はロードバランサが持つ形になります。CNはユーザーがアクセスしてくるホスト名=ロードバランサのホスト名になります。実サーバにはロードバランサがHTTPでアクセスするので証明書は不要です。

### SSL(TLS)の終端は実サーバが行い、ロードバランサはSSL(TLS)を透過する

証明書は実サーバが持ちます。CNはユーザーがアクセスしてくるホスト名なので、上と同様ロードバランサのホスト名になります。ロードバランサは通信をトンネルするだけなので、証明書は不要です。

いずれにせよ、実サーバのホスト名を持つ証明書はアクセスしてくるユーザーに対するサービス上は必須ではありません。システム構成上、または管理上必要でない限り、安易に実サーバのホスト名を持つ証明書を発行しないようにしましょう。

> また、SSL化が終わったロードバランサー直下のサーバはロードバランサー以外からの接続をNGにすれば宜しいのでしょうか?

ロードバランサがリバースプロキシ型の場合はその通りです。トランスペアレント/NAT型の場合、サーバからはクライアントが直接接続してくるように見えるので、接続を制限してはいけません(というかできません)